# Copied a code from excel 2010 to excel 2013 and it is not working

Tags: vba

I Would like to explain the problem here.

I wrote a code in excel vba in my computer which has excel  2010 on it, and then I copied that same code to another computer which has 2013. I want to point that I checked the files I copied and I've changed the paths accordingly.
Basically My code is a Userform that is made in one workbook called "FP Invoice", which takes data from another workbook which is called **"Customers List"**.

When the user form initializes it will open the workbook "Customers List"
and it will also assign a combobox rowsource to one named range called **"CustomerName"**.

The code follows... when the combobox value changes it should take data from the workbook (Customers List) and fill it in two textboxes in the userform.

***Here is the code:***

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'opening the workbook "Customers List"
Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Watex\Desktop\Experiment Invoice\Customers List.xlsx"
'Defining ComboBox rowSource
Me.ComboBox1.RowSource = "'Customers List.xlsx'!CustomerName"

End Sub

'Combobox Changes 
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Me.TextBox1.Value = ""
Me.TextBox2.Value = ""

Dim x As Long

Dim lastrow As Long

'I declare a variable named lastrow to get the last row in the range
lastrow = Workbooks("Customers List").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "c").End(xlUp).Row


For x = 1 To lastrow


Select Case Me.ComboBox1

Case [CustomerName].Cells(x, 1)

[CustomerName].Cells(x, 1).Activate

Me.TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
Me.TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)

End Select
Next x

End Sub
```

CustomerName is a dynamic range I have named in workbook ("Customers List") to the right of this range there are values like "address" and "ID" of the customers
then Im having textbox1 & textbox2 filled with the address & ID  of the Customers 
depending on the customername which is the value of the combobox.

The Problem I'm getting is "**Subscript out of range**" and when I press debug the following code gets highlighted:

```
lastrow = Workbooks("Customers List").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
```

I've already checked the names of the workbooks, sheets and path everything is correct and I want to point that this error occurs when i try to change the value of the combobox. combobox has already taken the values of the range. but the code for some reason won't work.
I already tried to remove the variable and put a number for example for x=1 to 80
and it worked.

Sorry for taking too much of your time, I'm beginner with VBA. I also apologize for my weak English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add the extension to the name, so change the line to

```
lastrow = Workbooks("Customers List.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
```

But this was true for earlier versions Excel already, so I doubt that this code ever worked.

However, a better solution would be to assign the workbook to a variable when you open it and use this variable when accessing the workbook.

```
Dim wb as workbook
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'opening the workbook "Customers List"
    set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Watex\Desktop\Experiment Invoice\Customers List.xlsx")
    ...
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    ...
    lastrow = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "c").End(xlUp).Row
    ...
end sub
```

Comment: Hi Thomas!
Thank you for your quick answer, it worked perfectly. I only ask myself how this code worked on 2010 version of excel! I was looking everywhere for the solution never thought it would be that simple.
Thanks again, :)

Comment: @M.Rabai: Glad I could help. Pls accept this answer so that others can see that no more help is needed.